# "Global" controls (does not contain a definition) in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, button, controls, global

I am a beginner programmer and I want to develop a small game project for practice, and for so I am making some tests first.
 In this test, my program generates a label programmatically, and I want the button to delete it when it is pressed. The problem is, it says that there is no definition for myLabel, so I suppose I should make myLabel a "global" control, but I don't know how. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Here's my code so far:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {  
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Label myLabel = new Label();
            this.Controls.Add(myLabel);
            myLabel.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            myLabel.Text = "Yay!";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(Label.myLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it a class private field

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private  Label myLabel;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myLabel = new Label();
        this.Controls.Add(myLabel);
        myLabel.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        myLabel.Text = "Yay!";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Controls.Remove(myLabel);
    }
```